# Statistical test to find variable causing failure

Tags: r, correlation, sampling, multivariate-analysis

I have a database with tests that are either a pass or fail and around 25 description fields. Each description field is either a boolean or has between 3 and 10 options.

I'd like to hook into my Postgres database using R and extract a subset of data that's hopefully representative of the entire database. Then I'd like to find out which fields correlate to test failures.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What exactly is your question here? Are you wondering how to get R to communicate w/ your Postgres database? (If so, this Q belongs on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) rather than here.) Are you wondering how to extract a representative subsample? how to conduct correlational analyses? something else?

Comment: I'm a coder, primarily, so my chief concern is how to do the statistical analysis. I'm sure I can figure out how to make the database connection.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to sample from your database? Is it huge?

Since your dependent variable (success, failure) is a dichotomy, you want logistic regression, probably.  In `R` this is available through `glm` with `family = binomial`.

If your data is observational then you can't say anything about 'cause' only about relationship.

Comment: I would like a sample because I'm going to do daily tests that take ~15 seconds per test and my test subject pools is between 25k and 100k. Even if I can't say that the variable is a cause for sure, it would be good to see which are related

Answer (score 0):

I take it you want to do variable selection with a dichotomous outcome variable. Using L1-regularized (LASSO) logistic regression would be an option. You can read about it in [this book](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/), and use the R packages `penalized` (allowing unpenalized covariables) or `glmnet` for doing it.

Some of your explanatory variables are polytomous, if I understand correctly. For these, the LASSO will select individual levels ("options") and not variables.

For information on how to use your Postgres database with R, as already mentioned, stack overflow is the more appropriate place to ask, and I'd be astonished if there wasn't already an explanation of how to do it there.